# Content appears a few seconds after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `switch` statement which will show a `div` based on what `number` is returned.

What's happening is:

- User goes to URL
- Default content loads in first (content that is not effected by the `switch` statement).
- After a few seconds delay, the `div` that is shown by the `switch` statement will just render in.

What I'm trying to achieve is  way to load in the relevant `div` from the `switch` statement alongside the default content (`.default`).

Current approach:

```js
var number = 50;

switch (true){
  case(number >= 25):
    $('.contentOne').removeClass('dontShow').addClass('show');
    break;

  case (number <= 24):
    $('.contentTwo').removeClass('dontShow').addClass('show');
    break;

}
```

```css
.dontShow{
  display:none;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero">

  <div class="default">
  This content will load in by default
  </div>
  
  <div class="contentOne dontShow">
      <h1>This is text for content 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="contentTwo dontShow">
      <h1>This is text for content 2</h1>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This is known as a Flash of Unstyled Content (or FOUC) caused by the DOM being loaded and then amended after waiting for the document.ready event to fire. To fix this in your case you need to make everything hidden by default (using CSS) and then have your logic show the relevant elements all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .dontShow {
        display:none;
      }

      .show {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var number = 50;

      switch (true) {
        case(number >= 25):
          $('.contentOne').removeClass('dontShow').addClass('show');
          break;

        case (number <= 24):
          $('.contentTwo').removeClass('dontShow').addClass('show');
          break;

      }
      
      $(document).ready(function() {
       // When document has been loaded, the page shows its content 
        $("body").removeClass('dontShow');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="dontShow">

    <div class="hero">
      <div class="default">
       This content will load in by default
      </div>
      <div class="contentOne dontShow">
          <h1>This is text for content 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="contentTwo dontShow">
          <h1>This is text for content 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

> Notice that you're using an outdated version of JQuery, so I put in the code the newest one:
>   
>   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
>   
>   To see deprecated methods in the new release check [this link](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.4/)